# C Matrix redimensioning leading to segfault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, segmentation-fault

I've got a array of strings (char**) and I need to do some redimensioning on it when it has reached its capacity. So, in this function I create a new array, allocate a size two time bigger than before, and for each string in the old array I allocate space for the new array and copy the content. Code is as follows:

```
void matrix_double (char ***arrayptr, int *size) {
    char **array = *arrayptr, **newarr;
    int i, wordsize;
    newarr = malloc (*size * 2);
    for (i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        wordsize = strlen (array[i]);
        newarr[i] = malloc (wordsize + 1);
        strcpy (newarr[i], array[i]);
        free (array[i]);
    }
    *size *= 2;
    free (array);
    *arrayptr = newarr;
}
```

However, I'm getting a lot of segfaults when allocating space for the new strings in the 7th line. According to Valgrind, those `malloc` commands are allocating space from within the space allocated for the array, which is small - I'm using arrays of 10 or 20 strings at most - and so it overflows to other allocated areas, causing segfaults. If I bump the array memory allocation up (such as `malloc (*size * 200)` everything runs smoothly.

Any ideas on what's happening? Haven't seen this behavior anywhere else.

Comment: `malloc (*size * 2);` - you seem to have forgotten you should be allocating arrays of *pointers* in some places; not just chars.

Comment: When you're resizing the array, you don't have to create copies of the strings; you could simply assign the pointer in the old array to the corresponding pointer in the new array.  That would save a lot of copying if your array is of any size.  You should consider the merits (and portability demerits) of [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).  You also need to decide how you would handle memory allocation failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc` argument is size in bytes. So you should call it like

`malloc(sizeof(char *) * (*size) * 2);`

By calling

`malloc(*size * 2);`

you are allocating `2*size` bytes of memory which is not enough for `size` of pointers.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking that a pointer would take only one byte, but it took 8 instead. Thanks!

Comment: @GustavoSilva pointers take 32 bit on 32-bit system and 64 bit on 64-bit system. So don't hardcode it